# Would it be possible to genetically modify a chimpanzee to be intelligent

Tags: internal-consistency

If a scientist in a lab wanted to create chimpanzees as intelligent as humans would it be possible for the scientists to alter the chimps dna so that it would be as intelligent as a human being.

Comment: They can alter it until it looks like human DNA is they want. But if they want to make a animal that looks like a chimp and is as smart as a human, it would be harder.

Comment: human level intelligent is a trade off, the human brain consumes a lot of energy even when idling so the energy comes from food which must be pre-digested (cooked) as we lack the kind of stomach that can extract efficiently (why do you think some animals have powerful acid like vulture or many stomachs like cow) in short you can have a chimp running the oval office (makes no diff) but it's brain cannot function properly (again no diff)... that's just my 2¢

Comment: I'm sort of torn about this. This is basically just a question about real-world genetic engineering. The answer is no, but a detailed explanation is out of scope of both my knowledge and this site. However, it isn't like Biology.SE is going to take a question this conjectural either. Its kind of homeless question, so I won't vote to close, but it really isn't a great question anyways.

Comment: @kingledion A very interesting analysis of the question's status RE the Stack Exchanges. Although it is more speculative than an application of real-world genetic engineering suggests. There are so many factors determining intelligence that we don't understand to put this outside real-world, contemporary science. If there are ways of doing this, we presently don't know them. We do get quite a few homeless questions. Not belonging anywhere on SE & not bad enough to close. It's a conundrum.

Comment: Jayden Harris - do you want the scientist to make the Chimps dumber in order to make them equal to Humans? Just Kidding.  Seriously, how close to Human intelligence is Chimp intelligence?  It is certainly possible that the average Chimp intelligence level is already high enough for an objective  observer to consider that Chimps, like Humans, are partly or even fully intelligent and thus people..

Answer (score 4):

Chimpanzees already ARE [intelligent](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/07/140710-intelligence-chimpanzees-evolution-cognition-social-behavior-genetics/); perhaps it doesn't seem so compared to a human, but they have a basic capability for language, tools and a social structure.

These questions are always tricky because different people weigh the term '[intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence)' with different semantic connotations. For most people, intelligence is synonymous with knowledge; Person A knows something I don't, therefore he's intelligent. This is not actually the case. Person A can be more knowledgeable, but intelligence is about what you can do with the knowledge and information you possess, not how much of it you possess. A smart person with less information can (in most normal circumstances) achieve the same results as a less smart person can with more information. (This is a simplification for brevity, but carries the key intent)

I've written a program that plays pick-up-sticks with you. You get to pick the starting count of sticks, how many you can pick up each time, and whether last to pick up wins or loses. It's very hard to beat. In some configurations, it's impossible to beat. Is that because it's intelligent? No, it's because pick-up-sticks is a Turing complete game; completely solvable via a simple maths equation. When I teach people the equation, they can beat the program every time because they (avoid the unwinnable scenarios and) play according to the math.

At first, the game looks smart. When you realise what it's doing, you see that it's just blindly following a simple equation.

For the purposes of this question, I've made the players who can now beat the game more knowledgeable; I haven't made them smarter, or more intelligent. That brings me to the most important point; in what way do you want chimpanzees to be more intelligent?

Do you want them to be able to design and construct houses? Use formal logic? Understand how to (and actually make) paints and then create paintings of nature? Do you want them to be able to design and operate nuclear power plants?

How many of us can actually do anything on this list ourselves?

I'm not saying that chimpanzees are AS intelligent as humans; Sure, DNA could be altered a little to give them larger cerebral cortexes and the like, but what we often define as intelligence is more a mix of intelligence (latent capability) and knowledge. Ice age men were no less intelligent than us; they just had a lot less information at their fingertips than we do.

The one differentiator between us and chimpanzees is that we've got a far more sophisticated language structure and that (combined with writing and now the internet) allows us to cheaply and quickly pass on our knowledge to others, allowing them to build on it with their own perspectives and experience. It would be interesting to know just how capable chimpanzees could become if they had that same ability, rather than having to learn most things from scratch every generation.

Comment: I completely agree. The question appears to consider intelligence as mainly genetic and existing on a quantifiable linear scale and, of course, a scale which is essentially artificial because we plot what we think significant points based upon our ideas of what (human) intelligence is.

Answer (score 0):

No,
This is not currently possible as we still don't fully understand the genetics behind intelligence.

We also lack the technology for manipulations of this magnitude.

Could this someday be possible?

Sure, we could theoretically make them smarter than humans currently. The real question is if they are still considered chimps

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is theoretically possible. Chimp DNA differs from Human DNA by only 2% so theoretically changing that 2% would provide the change you require.

However this would be an almost impossibly difficult task. We have no idea how it might be achieved currently and even if we could what you would end up with is a bizarre way of creating a human being from a chimpanzee.

If what you want is something that looks like a Chimp but acts like a human then that is even more difficult as we have no idea which parts of the 2% chimp-human DNA difference should be set as chimp or as human to achieve this.

Comment: ... I agree, I think changing that 2% will give you another human, not a chimp-wth-intelligence.  I mean, there wouldn't be any % difference left in the DNA, right?  To make a chimp-with-intelligence, I think you'd need to keep that 2% difference and make up the intelligence gap in the other 98% (yes, that would mean chimp-with-intelligence is *less* like human-folk than chimp-without-intelligence, but how else to be sure it's still a chimp?).